# table does not respond correctly to state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I have already been able to add elements to a table and it updates correctly when changing the state, but when I try to delete an element using slice the state seems to update correctly deleting the desired item, but when the table is re-rendered the last item always disappears, and the item that should disappear is still being displayed, I don't understand why this is happening

For example, I have rows 1, 2, and 3. I delete 2, the status is updated correctly, and rows 1 and 3 remain, but when re-rendering the table, 1 and 2 visually appear, that is, the last item always disappears in the table.

```
const [groups, setGroups] = useState([]);

...

function onDelCriterion(indexGroup, indexCriterion, event){
    setGroups( groups => {
      return groups.map((group, indexGroup) => {
        if (indexGroup == indexCriterion){
          let newArray = group.criteria.slice()          // copy array
          newArray.splice(ind, 1);                       // del item
          return {...group, criteria : newArray }        // update with copy
        }
        else {
          return group;
        }
      })
    });
  }
```

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="groups"  style={styles.tableRadius}>
  <tbody>
  {
    groups.map((group, indexGp)=>{
    const {name, criteria} = group;
    return(
      <tr >
        <td  style={styles.tableRadius} class="">
          <div class=" col-12 d-flex p-2">
            <input type="text" onChange={(evnt)=>(onChangeNameGroup(indexGp, evnt))} /> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning col-1" >Delete</button>
          </div>

          <p name="criteria_label" type="text"> Criteria </p>

          <table class="table table-bordered" id="criteria_by_group" >
            <thead class="table-success">
              <tr class='col-12 '>
                <th scope="col" style={{"width": "32%"}}>Field</th>
                <th scope="col" style={{"width": "32%"}}>Is</th>
                <th scope="col" style={{"width": "32%"}}>To Value</th>
                <th scope="col" style={{"width": "4%"}}> </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {
              criteria.map((criterion, index)=>{
              const {field, operator, value} = criterion;
              return(
                <tr > 
                  <td> <input type="text" defaultValue={field} onChange={(evnt)=>(onChangeCriterion("field", name, index, evnt))} class="border-0" style={{"width": "100%"}}/> </td>
                  <td> <input type="text" defaultValue={operator} onChange={(evnt)=>(onChangeCriterion("operator", name, index, evnt))} class="border-0" style={{"width": "100%"}}/></td>
                  <td> <input type="text" defaultValue={value} onChange={(evnt)=>(onChangeCriterion("value", name, index, evnt))} class="border-0" style={{"width": "100%"}}/></td>
                  <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick={(evnt)=>(onDelCriterion(indexGp, index, evnt))} style={{"width": "100%"}}>X</button> </td>
                </tr>  // DELETE BUTTON
              )
              })
            }
            </tbody>
          </table>  
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                  <button id="select_xmls" onClick={(evnt)=>(onNewCriterion(name, evnt))} class="btn btn-dark" type="button" aria-expanded="false" style={{"align" : "right"}}>
                    New Criterion 
                  </button>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            )

            })
          }
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a unique `key` to each element returned but the `.map()` method, otherwise, such problems occur  :

```html
<tr key={indexGp}>
  <td>
    //...
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {criteria.map((criterion, index) => {
          //...
          return <tr key={index}>
            //...
          </tr>
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```